# cannot convert value of type NSURL? to expected

Tags: swift, nsurl

I am running into an issue in my Swift code where I get an error message from this code segment saying:

> "cannot convert value of type NSURL? to expected argument type 'URL'

```
var url = NSURL (string: "http://google.com")
var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url)   --> this line is where the error occurs
self.webView!.loadReuqest(req)
```

I am using Xcode 9.1 which is version 4 of Swift. That is the only error I am receiving when trying to build my app to view the webpage.

Whole Swift code is below.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var containerView : UIView! = nil
    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.view = self.webView!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var url = NSURL(string:"http://google.com")
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `NSURL` instead of `URL`?

Comment: Simple rule: Do not use `NS...` classes if there is a native Swift equivalent (in Swift 3+ there is `URL` and `URLRequest`). Actually the error message includes two errors: The bridge cast and the unwrapped optional.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were following a Swift 2 example.  You should drop the NS form URL and from URLRequest as they are part of Foundation as of Swift 3.

```
let url = URL(string:"http://google.com")!
let req = URLRequest(url:url)
self.webView!.load(req)
```